# Resolution for External Monitor

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution

16.04: A 1600x900 monitor is connected to a docked laptop and was working well for months.  This morning, the resolution is 1024X768 and 1600X900 is not an option in the settings

1. What can be tested to determine why this happened?
2. What can be done to enable 1600X900 resolution?

External monitor is labeled as 'unknown display'.  Diagnostic questions are appreciated and welcomed